# AngularJs (ngResource ) : Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I want to use ngResource with HTTP but i have this error :

> Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Angular ngResource</title>
<script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

    myApp.factory('UserService',['$resource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/:user',{user: "@user"});
    }]);

    myApp.controller('produitsCtrl', function($scope, $http,UserService) {

        $scope.users = UserService.query();

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" >

    <div ng-controller="produitsCtrl"> 
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="x in users">
            {{ x.name + ', ' + x.username }}
          </li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and my json file is : **http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    }
]
```

ANY ONE HAVE AN IDEA PLEASE ?

Comment: Typo, what is `ngRessource`? extra `s`

Comment: @PSL addtional thing was `script` tag angular not closed properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in `ngRessource` it should be `ngResource`

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);
```

Also You made angular js `script` reference self closing which was totally wrong. you should close angular script tag properly. Look below.

```
<script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, finally i find the error on the script link, I replaced `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-resource.min.js"/>`  by `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-resource.min.js"></script>`  and now it is WORK,  thank You a Lot : )

Comment: Yes, sure, but how i colde my request please ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the dependencies you provided to the app module definition.
Change `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRessource']);` to `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);`.