# MVC4 after bundling angularjs not working throwing exception

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-bundling

In my MVC4 application working fine with angularjs and have no errors.if i bundle js and css using

**BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;**

i got uncaught error.
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0

[image]

**Controller.js**

```
App.controller('userController',
  ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', 'exDialog', '$stateParams', 'toaster', 'Upload', '$modal',
  function ($rootScope, $scope, $state, exDialog, $stateParams, toaster, Upload, $modal) {

//Logic here

}]);
```

**Solution**

the issue is while we do minification. The directive names are changed with single characters for minification.

**issue Js finding method**

```
public class NonMinifying : IBundleTransform
    {
        public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse bundle)
        {
            if (bundle == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("bundle");
            }

            //context.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetLastModifiedFromFileDependencies();
            foreach (var file in bundle.Files)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddFileDependency(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(file.IncludedVirtualPath));
            }

        }
    }
```

create the bundle like below code and bundle your js one by one into this.if worked fine change the next js
like this i found the issue line.Hope above details will help to find issue line in js

```
  bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/appScriptsnonmini", new NonMinifying())
              .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/app", "*.js")                     
                );
```

Comment: how yo have created your controller can you show it.

Comment: posted controller declaration
var App = angular.module('sapp', [ //Logic here ]);

Comment: If you are on mvc 4 then make sure that your .js files do not end with a comment similar to //@SomeText. When the bundler concatenates files the comment at the end can spill onto the next file. It has been fixed, however you are using an older version.

Comment: check if  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604838/angularjs-ngresource-error-injectormodulerr-http-errors-angularjs-or) can help you.

Comment: Try clearing your cache.

Comment: Hi @OrelEraki, I have cleared the cache.even i have checked with  incognito window also no luck.@lrb i have checked my entire solution there is no words like "//@" i am using .net framework is 4.0.@viplock my code is working fine without "EnableOptimizations" properties .if i make enable it i am getting uncaught error.Thanks dudes

Comment: hey @Dinesh Kumar did u find a solution for your error? im having the same issue.